# Sitecore WebFoms for Marketers module

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I want to ask you how it will be better to implement: using Sitecore WebForms for Marketers module or in standard .ascx sublayout.

[image: Form example]

So I need to implement huge form with dynamic dropdowns, date pickers, checkboxes, radiobuttons, etc. This form contains also dynamic adding new controls (see description in attachment above). So is it possible to create this form in Sitecore WebForms for Marketers module or it will be easier to write it as standard form in ascx.

This form will be saved to sitecore database.

Please answer if somebody have already done smth like this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To my kowledge it isn't possible to do this *out of the box* with WFFM in Sitecore.

I guess the first question to ask is: *do you or your customer want/need to be able to manage forms themselves without developer interaction?*

If the answer to this question is yes, then you could try to implement this with WFFM, otherwise it may be easier to just implement as a normal sublayout.

**EDIT**

One other thing you could also do is to create a form, then use the 'export to ascx' function.  You can look at the generated code to see how the data is written to the WFFM database - this way you can have your custom form functionality but still leverage the reporting functionality in the Sitecore client. If you have some decision tree-like logic for displaying the different fields you could probably drive this from Sitecore content items as well.

Comment: Thnx, will implement as sublayout.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge you can create this form with the help of Web form for marketer but in this case you need to create some custom fields and update these fields as per your requirement.
To Create custom field create field under /sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Field Types/Custom location and in custom field define your created custom class and assembly.

You can update design by applying your custom css classes.

Class you can create under /sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Meta data/Css Classes location and apply class on specific control.